# nunit-agent seems to be failing to load probing privatePath from tests configuration

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit, probing

Previously, when I had only Visual Studio 2010, my unit tests were executing fine.

Basically, my tests are composed of two files: UnitTests.dll and UnitTests.dll.config. Where UniTests.dll.config had a custom probing privatePath (e.g., Public;Extensions;Lib)

In order to execute, I used to follow this workflow:
1. I copied both files (i.e. UnitTests.dll and .config) to the folder were my application under test is located.
2. Open NUnit gui.
3. Execute the tests with ShadowCopy disabled, because my tests need to load the dlls from my application under test.

This was working fine!

After I installed Visual Studio 2012, the tests were not running anymore. And later, I figured out a workaround, but it is something that I don't want to use in my solution.

Now, I have to follow this workflow to make the tests running:

1. I copy both files (i.e. UnitTests.dll and .config) to the folder where my application under test is located.
2. I copy all the NUnit installation files (i.e. nunit-agent, nunit-console, etc.) to the folder where my application under test is located.
3. I change the probing privatePath from nunit-agent.dll.config in order to include the same paths from my UnitTests.dll.config.
4. Open NUnit gui which is located in my application under test folder.
5. Execute the tests with ShadowCopy disabled.

Note that I had to include steps 2 and 3 in order to run my unit tests. Somehow, I think nunit-agent.dll is not loading the probing privatePath from the config file of my test assembly.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Does anyone have a workaround where I don't need to change the nunit-agent.dll.config and copy the nunit installation files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does data driven unit test fail in vs2012 when it worked fine in vs2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025719/why-does-data-driven-unit-test-fail-in-vs2012-when-it-worked-fine-in-vs2010)