# Why does data driven unit test fail in vs2012 when it worked fine in vs2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, data-driven-tests, deploymentitem

I have some data driven unit tests that were working just fine in Visual Studio 2010. These tests were implemented using the following pattern.

```cs
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("path_to_data_dir_relative_to_solution\\my_data.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\my_data.xml", "Token", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    // Arrange
    const string EXPECTED_PARAM_NAME = "table";
    string data = TestContext.DataRow["Data"].ToString();
    var sut = new MyClassUnderTest();

    // Act
    sut.DoSomething(data);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(sut.DidSomething);
}
```

Here is my solution structure.

- MySolutionFolder

  - MyTestProjectFolder
  - MyTestDataFolder

    - my_data.xml

When I run the same tests in Visual Studio 2012, they fail with the following error message.

Result Message: The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library. Error details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why are my unit tests suddenly failing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010, the `DeploymentItem` attribute is relative to the **solution**, but in Visual Studio 2012, it is relative to the **project**. Simply specify the `DeploymentItem` path relative to the project folder and the unit tests will start working again.

For more info see the following link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/4a8403a2-b495-4120-aad3-0d0becc7e45e/